# convert epoch time to NSDate in cocoa/iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsdate

I have the value of the epoch time like say 123456789, now I want to convert this into `NSDate` in cocoa framework. Can anyone show me?

thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend!

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:123456789];
```

Comment: Stack overflow is my faster friend.

Comment: If the date comes in milliseconds you need to divide that number by 1000 first!

Answer (score 7):

Since this is a high hit, going to contribute. Note that just converting to NSDate will put it into the UTC timezone. Then you have to convert over to your timezone if you want to display it to the user, from [Convert epoch time to NSDate with good timezone with Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655446/convert-epoch-time-to-nsdate-with-good-timezone-with-objective-c):

```
// Convert NSString to NSTimeInterval
NSTimeInterval seconds = [epochTime doubleValue];

// (Step 1) Create NSDate object
NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to UTC %@", epochTime, epochNSDate);

// (Step 2) Use NSDateFormatter to display epochNSDate in local time zone
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to %@", epochTime, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:epochNSDate]);

// (Just for interest) Display your current time zone
NSString *currentTimeZone = [[dateFormatter timeZone] abbreviation];
NSLog (@"(Your local time zone is: %@)", currentTimeZone);
```