# Convert epoch time to NSDate with good timezone with Objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

how I can convert an epoch time value to NSDate. For example I use this value : 1310412600000. and I am in the EDT time zone.

When I try this :

```
NSString *bar = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epoch] description];
```

I got a wrong value...

What is the good way? I spend a lot of time with that....

Thanks

Comment: As Kal mentions, what is the type and value of `epoch` at the time of the call?

Comment: Whats wrong? The entire date or just the time. Please post the expected results and the actual results.

Comment: Note that your value, `1310412600000`, was the epoch-delta in milliseconds. Built in iOS functions expect seconds. That's likely why you were getting wrong values.

Answer (score 31):

Epoch time (also known as "Unix" and "POSIX" time) is the number of seconds since the start of 1970. You can convert epoch time to NSDate with this algorithm:

1. Instantiate NSDate object and pass the epoch time as a parameter to NSDate's initWithTimeIntervalSince1970 initializer. **You're done.** The NSDate object is set to the epoch time. NSDate stores times internally in the UTC time zone. It's up to you how it is displayed.
2. [Optional] Format your NSDate to the appropriate time zone with an NSDateFormatter.

Here's the code I used:

```
    // Sample string epochTime is number of seconds since 1970
NSString *epochTime = @"1316461149";

// Convert NSString to NSTimeInterval
NSTimeInterval seconds = [epochTime doubleValue];

// (Step 1) Create NSDate object
NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to UTC %@", epochTime, epochNSDate);

// (Step 2) Use NSDateFormatter to display epochNSDate in local time zone
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to %@", epochTime, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:epochNSDate]);

// (Just for interest) Display your current time zone
NSString *currentTimeZone = [[dateFormatter timeZone] abbreviation];
NSLog (@"(Your local time zone is: %@)", currentTimeZone);
```

Comment: Epoch time is number of SECONDS since 1970 (not milliseconds). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time  .... Don't divide by 1000

Comment: Thanks! I can't remember what I was doing back in 2011 that caused me to be working in milliseconds, but you're quite right. I've removed the step to divide by 1000.

Comment: I used your answer after I changed that small thing though, so thank you!

Comment: @SteveHHH It's that OP's question uses milliseconds. That's why you were doing that

Answer (score 6):

Per [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970%3a), `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` runs from January 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT. So you should be getting results four hours later than those you really want.

Hence the simplest thing — if you don't mind hard coding the offset from GMT to EDT — would seem to be:

```
[[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epoch] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-240]

// or:
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epoch - 240]
```

Though to eliminate arbitrary constants (and be a little cleaner), you probably want something like:

```
NSTimeZone *EDTTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EDT"];

NSInteger secondsDifferenceFromGMT =
    [EDTTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]];

NSDate *startOfEpoch = 
                 [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:secondsDifferenceFromGMT];

...

NSDate *newDate = [startOfEpoch dateByAddingTimeInterval:firstInterval]; // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the value in seconds?

The method accepts value in seconds , not milliseconds.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html