# Converting a unix timestamp to NSdate using local timezone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm getting some `start_times` and `end_times` in the form of `NSDecimalNumber`s back from an API request.

I have successfully been able to convert these `NSDecimalNumber`s into `NSDate`s, but the code is not taking time zones into account.

I need for it to use the timezone that is default on the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert epoch time to NSDate in cocoa/iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2609561/608157)

Comment: Another possible duplicate is [Convert epoch time to NSDate with good timezone with Objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6655446/608157)

Comment: There are other as well... use the search field in the upper right corner before asking questions. It's the first topic on the ["How to ask" page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Well, i always use the searchbar so dont be so quick to judge. I just hadnt heard of epoch time before your comment. Unix timestamp, however, im familiar with. Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should do what you need with current locale

```
double unixTimeStamp =1304245000;
NSTimeInterval _interval=unixTimeStamp;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 9):

Unix time [doesn't have a time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). it's defined in UTC as the number of seconds since midnight Jan 1 1970.

You should get the NSDates in the correct time zone by using

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:myEpochTimestamp];
```

Comment: Hello David, which one is correct yours or the accepted one?

Comment: Both answers do the same when it comes to creating the date object. The rest is just formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm only concern for this line `[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];` output may be vary?

Comment: Yes, the output will be different depending on the local. Again, that is just about formatting the date object as a string. It's the same date.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this..

```
NSDate* sourceDate = ... // your NSDate

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];
```